Why are my users unable to create schemas in Azure SQL when one of their Entra Groups have db_ddladmin, db_datareader and db_datawriter roles?
I am not sure what I am doing wrong here but when users try and make a schema
CREATE SCHEMA [TEST]
they get the following error:-
Failed to execute query. Error: The user attempting to perform this operation does not have permission as it is currently logged in as a member of an Azure Active Directory (AAD) group but does not have an associated database user account. A user account is necessary when creating an object to assign ownership of that object. To resolve this error, either create an Azure AD user from external provider, or alter the AAD group to assign the DEFAULT_SCHEMA as dbo, then rerun the statement.
The groups principal is created in the databse, has the right roles and has the default schema of dbo
proof from database
My user is within the group
proof I am in Entra group
Updates
select SCHEMA_NAME()

comes back with dbo
Changing my script to
CREATE SCHEMA [Test] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]

Results in the same error
I have added the explit permission to create schema to the principal and also get the same error
permissions table

The error seems to be telling you the problem here; an Entra Group can't be used as the owner of the schema, so the CREATE fails. What happens if they define the owner of the schema, such as CREATE SCHEMA test AUTHORIZATION dbo;?

Thanks for the response! I did actually try it with that too but I get the same error message

Does this answer your question? Second member of Azure AD group can not create schema in Azure SQL database

Thanks again Thom, but explicitly adding the parent schema doesn't change anything and I have already set the default schema (dbo) for the principle as that post suggests doing.

@SamHamer Please check the below answer and let me know if there is any issue

As per doc

When a user without a database user account creates an object without specifying an existing schema, a database principal and default schema will be automatically created in the database for that user. The created database principal and schema will have the same name as the name that user used when connecting to SQL Server (the SQL Server authentication login name or the Windows user name).

As per the error you need to create the user explicitly for Azure Entra id and then you need to create an object in database.
CREATE USER [abc@xyz.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

Or you can Add default schema for Entra group user as dbo while creation of it or you can alter the user.
CREATE USER [Entragroup] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;


this is already the case I am afraid :(

I had the same issue, and I managed to create a schema only after I have added AUTHORIZATION:
CREATE SCHEMA [name] AUTHORIZATION [groupName];  


afraid its the same error when I do that
